# Is drywall required over our insulated laundry room wall?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

We recently had some drywall removed in our laundry room so our plumber could replace our old flex dryer vent with a safer rigid one. How important is it to repatch the drywall? Is it just a cosmetic question? Thanks!

[image: laundry room]

Answer (score 1):

Some regulations require that you cover that insulation facing for fire resistance.

Otherwise, no, drywall isn't required. It's cheap and fairly easy, though, so I'm not sure why you'd let your home's value and aesthetic qualities be degraded if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you wouldn't want to replace it even if it was just for cosmetics but there would probably be some air flow problems if it's left open There are always opening for pipes, AC vents, electrical lines, etc. in the ceiling area.It looks like there are open joists that air could be flowing into or out of decreasing the efficiency of your heating and cooling systems. Plus repairing the drywall will cut down on the noise from the washer and dryer to the areas above and along sides of the room.